# Best way to make a concept for a videogame model?

Tags: modeling

Im working on a little videogame with some friends, but we want to learn how to work like pros. I'm the one who does the concept art, and we divide the modeling work between each one of us. This means that I will have to draw concepts that both I and them must look at when creating models. What's a good way of doing concept for videogame characters? Is the orthogonal projection the best or will it be fine with just a pair of sketches?

Edit: Maybe it will be better to ask this on a design forum rather than here?

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange. Unfortunately, your question is not well suited to the site. I suggest you ask it in the forums at Blender Artist or a similar site.

Comment: In general, the pros use sketches, but make sure they are to scale (orthagonal projected correctly). I'm not sure I understand your question. Is that all you wanted to know? (I would recommend Krita for drawing concepts. MyPaint is also easy to learn to use, and simple, yet makes good resaults.)

Comment: Actually, I just wanted to know if doing orthogonal projections is the best way to "show the others what to do", or there are more effective ways, when it comes to modeling, that's it. I know maybe it was a bit off-topic for this section, but I didn't know where to post it elsewhere.

Comment: Are you asking how best to use images for modeling? Or how to best draw images to be used for modeling?

Comment: The second one, which kind of images would be best as a base for modeling. For example, an orthogonal projection seems good since I can use the varius sides as a background and model my character on it, but I wonder if there are more "professional" ways.

Comment: Conceptual questions are mostly opinion based and are hard to answer "correctly" in this question and answer format. A forum format like blenderartists.org or other game developer forums might be a better place for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do my best to answer your question within the bounds of the Blender Stack Exchange focus.

If you've ever seen professional concept art, they often have 3 view of a character/concept object.

-Frontal
-Profile
-close up

This is so the entire concept can be displayed. In blender, the frontal and profile views are often used in character modeling.

A common practice is to enable the "insert images as planes" add-on and place the planes in front of and next to the character you are modeling.

There are many tutorials and examples of this. A quick internet search will probably prove fruitful.

I hope it helps!